# Pandas - drop rows based on two conditions on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Although there are several related questions answered in Pandas, I cannot solve this issue. I have a large dataframe (~ 49000 rows) and want to drop rows the meet two conditions at the same time(~ 120):

- For one column: an exact string
- For another column: a NaN value

My code is ignoring the conditions and no row is removed.

```
to_remove = ['string1', 'string2'] 
df.drop(df[df['Column 1'].isin(to_remove) & (df['Column 2'].isna())].index, inplace=True)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling `drop`, and passing the `index`, You can create the mask for the condition for which you want to keep the rows, then take only those rows. Also, the logic error seems to be there, you are checking two different condition combined by `AND` for the same column values.

```py
df[~(df['Column1'].isin(to_remove) & (df['Column2'].isna()))]
```

Also, if you need to check in the same column, then you probably want to combine the conditions by or i.e. `|`
If needed, you can `reset_index` at last.

Also, as side note, your list `to_remove` has two same string values, I'm assuming thats a typo in the question.

Comment: This works but does not totally answers OP question. Why does his `drop` method do not work ?

Comment: @BenjaminRio I was updating the answer, thanks for your comment.

Comment: `df['Column2'].isna()` doesn't need to be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: @fsimonjetz Yes it doesn't I just copied and pasted what OP had mentioned

Comment: I removed the typos in the question. Will check your proposed solutions. Mask method I tried before but did not solved my issue.